# How to pass object to another class?

Tags: php

I have class `B`. In this class I create object `classB()`. And I have a question how can I pass this `new classB()` to another class ?

```
class A
{
public classB $classB;

public function __construct()
{
    
    $this->classB = new classB();
}
}
```

```
class C
{
public function example()
{
   /// here I want to object new classB() created in class A
}
}
```

Comment: The object `$classB` is not in class A. Every instance of class A gets its own `$classB`. Please keep reading whatever tutorial you're learning from. Also, try to read others' code. I believe you're just a small step away from these things making sense.

Answer (score 2):

If I take your code, only slightly altered:

```
class A
{
    public $b;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->b = new B();
    }
}
```

Then continue to create an object from that class:

```
$a = new A();
```

Then I can access the public property `b`, which is an object of class `B`, like so:

```
$accessB = $a->b;
```

Now if you want to use property `b` in another class you can do:

```
class C
{
    public function example($anObject)
    {
       // here you can use $anObject
    }
}

$c = new C();
$c->example($a->b);
```

That's all there is to it.

Please, next time you want to provide an example, make it meaningful. So instead of say "class A" call it, for instance, "class Car", and "class Wheel". Using meaningful class names, that clearly relate to each other, helps to understand what you're doing and helps to get away from abstract code.